# how recursively to add some .txt files from a folder and sub folder's in Java

Tags: java

I have been trying to use some data from some txt files (I want to find some words in these txt files) from a folder and sub folder's recursively (I have to find these txt files from some folders that all of them are in the same folder) in Java, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "import"?

Comment: use .txt file data's

Comment: You're gonna need to include a lot more information here for anyone to be able to help you. What are you doing with the txt files?  Why are they stored in different directories? Are you trying to import every single txt file recursively from a start directory? Or only some of them.

Comment: I want to find some word in these txt files but i have to find these txt files from some folders that all of them are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this is good way for do it:

```
private static void addfiles (File input,ArrayList<File> files)
    {
        if(input.isDirectory())
        {
            ArrayList <File> path = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(input.listFiles()));
            for(int i=0 ; i<path.size();++i)
            {
                if(path.get(i).isDirectory())
                {
                    addfiles(path.get(i),files);
                }
                if(path.get(i).isFile())
                {
                    String name=(path.get(i)).getName();
                    if(name.lastIndexOf('.')>0)
                    {
                        int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                        String str = name.substring(lastIndex);
                        if(str.equals(".txt"))
                        {
                            files.add(path.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(input.isFile())
        {
            String name=(input.getName());
            if(name.lastIndexOf('.')>0)
            {
                int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                String str = name.substring(lastIndex);
                if(str.equals(".txt"))
                {
                    files.add(input);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void processInput(final String directoryName) {

    final File inputDirectory = new File(directoryName);
    for (final String inputFile : inputDirectory.list()) {
        final File file = new File(directoryName + File.separator
                + inputFile);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            processInput(directoryName + File.separator + inputFile);
        } else {
            processFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```